# Why the continous form in this answer

Tags: continuous

I’ve **been reading** online that people who purchased that record have not received it so I’m assuming he is being slow to ship

this is an email I received: my enquiry was about a record I bought but have not received .

I'd like to know why the author of this email used the continuous form, why not the simple form ? Is it because every time he has gone on line he has read it, I don't think so

Answer (score 1):

The use of [present perfect continuous (or present perfect progressive)](https://leo.stcloudstate.edu/grammar/tenses.html)  implies this is ongoing, i.e. `Present perfect progressive tense describes an action that began in the past, continues in the present, and may continue into the future.` If it happened a few times in the past *only*, your correspondent might have sent the following.

> I’ve read online that people who purchased that record have not received it so I’m assuming he is being slow to ship.

Comment: but i've read means it began in the past but goes  up to now but not continuously. I know that progressive  is for ongoing  action but what is ongoing the fact of reading? . How many reading can you do before using  the progressive form and futhermore if it  happened only in the past he would have used past simple read

Comment: There are subtle differences in the language, and in reality, native English speakers might choose different ways to say the same thing. `I've read` is strictly the past, though, but not including the present. BTW, 'readings' is the plural of 'reading'.

Comment: The act of reading itself may be in the past but the knowledge continuous into the present, so if I have read a book, I have finished reading but I know the content now. In your example "I've been reading" means a number of times, over a period of time continuing into the present.